# Get in backend images url of uploaded image

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

Is there any solution to get the full file path of a just uploaded image in the backend of octobercms?

I need to paste the image url in afterCreate() When I use `$image->getPath()` I get the follow error: "Call to a member function getPath() on a non-object"

If i try `$request->file('featured_image')` give me also the "Call to a member function file() on a non-object"

I try also `Input::file('featured_image')->getRealPath()` what give me also "Call to a member function getRealPath() on a non-object"

Is there any way to get the full file path of a just uploaded image in the backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work although I'm not 100% clear this is what you're actually trying to achieve.

Here's what a sample plugin class declaration would look like:

```
class Plugin extends PluginBase
{
    public function boot()
    {

        // Bind to afterCreate
        File::extend(function($model) {
            $model->bindEvent('model.afterCreate', function() use ($model) {
                // Do whatever with $model->getPath();
            });
        });

    }
}
```